# Log4j 2 : can't use the ContextMapLookup in RollingFileAppender fileName and filePattern

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j2, rollingfileappender

I am working on logging with log4j 2.0.2. I am trying to use the ContextMapLookup into the fileName and filePattern attribute of a RollingFileAppender but I can't make it work.

Here is my (simplified) Map initialization in a REST facade :

```
@GET
public Response logSomething(@QueryParam("param") String param) {
    ThreadContext.put("someName", "default");
    LOGGER.info("Param from query: {}", param);
    ThreadContext.clearMap();
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

And here is my (simplified to) configuration file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </Console>
    <RollingFile name="Rolling" 
                 fileName="logs/${ctx:someName}-webapps-metrics.log"
                 filePattern="logs/archives/${ctx:someName}-webapps-metrics-%i.log" >
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %m%n"/>
      <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 KB"/>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>

    <!-- My Logger using rollingFile -->
    <Logger name="com.ipanematech.rest.MyRESTFacade" level="info" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="Rolling" />
    </Logger>
    <Root level="warn">
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

A file named "{ctx" is created in the directory. It seems that the expression to get the context does not work in these attributes.

I tried to use the context in the PatternLayout of my appender and it worked well.

In fileName and filePattern, I tried different syntaxes but not one worked:

- ${ctx:someName} (like in the example above)
- $${ctx:someName}
- %X{someName}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RoutingAppender does what you want. See the log4j2 FAQ page for a [detailed example](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#separate_log_files).

Comment: Just one more question please: I can't understand why it does not work without the RoutingAppender. Using a RoutingAppender is OK for me, but out of curiosity, I just wonder why, technically, it not possible with a simple RollingFileAppender ?

Comment: The RoutingAppender has logic to log to multiple destinations and even create new files on the fly, where the RollingFileAppender has only one single destination file. RollingFileAppender can do rollover, but that only moves the (single) destination to a different file. It would be possible to combine that functionality into a single appender, but this design is more flexible and more powerful: it allows the "multiple destinations" capability to be used with all kind of appenders, instead of just the RollingFileAppender.

Comment: At the begining I was trying to use a system property to chose the directory for the log (${sys:catalina.base}) and I saw the jira LOG4J-829 you corrected in 2.1. Waiting for this version, I tried to put the transformed path in the context to use it it my file pattern. At this point I did not need a RootingAppender because I wanted only one destination file. Is there another work around for that Jira if we are using the 2.0.2 version ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, sorry. But 2.1 should be out soon, hopefully sometime next week.

Comment: Did you managed to do this with RoutigAppender? I have the same issue and i've prepared new cfg but no results :(