# Log4j2 Can't read ThreadConntext variables in the RoutingAppender

Tags: java, parsing, logging, log4j2

Firstly i've read this topic [Log4j 2 : can't use the ContextMapLookup in RollingFileAppender fileName and filePattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405456/log4j-2-cant-use-the-contextmaplookup-in-rollingfileappender-filename-and-fil)
I've prepared configuration as below:

```
<Configuration name="configuration">
    <Appenders>
        <Routing name="routing_1">
            <Routes>
                <Route>
                    <RollingFile append="true"
                                 fileName="logfile"
                                 filePattern="logfile.${mdc:User}-${mdc:Channel}.%i.log"
                                 name="routing_1">
                        <PatternLayout pattern="Thread=%tid [%X{MessageId}] %d %-11T %-5p [%c] - %m%n"/>
                        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
                        <Policies>
                            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20000KB"/>
                        </Policies>
                    </RollingFile>
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Routing>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger additivity="true"
                level="info"
                name="org.hibernate.type">
            <AppenderRef ref="routing_1"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And it is creating files `logfile.${mdc:User}-${mdc:Channel}.0.log, logfile.${mdc:User}-${mdc:Channel}.1.log (...)`
I tried using `%X{User}`, `%X{Channel}` and it resulted in files like:
`logfile.%X-%X.0.log, logfile.%X-%X.1.log (...)`
I've attached the debugger and found out that during PatternConverter creation in

```
PatternParser::createConverter
PatternParser::finalizeConverter
PatternParser::parse
PatternProcessor::ctr
```

There are only 4 rules {`%i`, `%d`, and two others that i don't remember} and neither of them handles `%X` clause. I recon this is the problem, but i don't know how i can control this in the middle of the library process.
Strangely `%X{MessageId}` substitution in `PatternLayout's pattern` works fine.

Any help guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to uncover the mystery.
To `<Routes>` element I've added a `pattern` attribute as follows

```
<Routes pattern="$${event:Level}">
```

I presume this means that this route will be choosen and evaluted while logEvent has specified level (which is always the case). That opens up the doors to look up any context variable in any numbers.
It is sad that there is so little information on how to use these...